# pipenv, jupyter and possibly other commands stopped working after upgrading python3.7 to python3.8

Tags: python, bash, pip, homebrew, upgrade

I upgraded python version from 3.7 to 3.8 using `brew upgrade python3` however after upgrading pipenv and jupyter commands stopped working. These are the commands I've ran as of now other commands may not be working as well.

This is the output when I ran pipenv:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pipenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This is the output when I ran the jupyter command:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So I opened up the file `/usr/local/bin/pipenv` and the interpreter declared at the top is `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`

So I changed it to `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.8` and ran pipenv command and this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pipenv import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipenv'
```

I ran `pip3 list` command and this was the output

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 49.2.0
wheel      0.34.2
```

So i went into `/usr/local/lib` and there were 2 folders named *python3.7* and *python3.8*. The *site-packages* folder in *python3.7* has all the modules I had previously installed but the *site-packages* folder in *python3.8* contains only 3 modules which I got using `pip3 list`.

I don't fully understand the issue but I think all the older commands are still linked to python3.7 interpreter which no longer exists and secondly all the site packages need to be in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, site-packages are per-interpreter-version. (Also, virtualenvs tend to break when you upgrade your Python version.)

Just reinstall the packages you need with your new Python 3.8 based `pip3`.

Comment: Okay! So i installed pipenv using the python3.8 based pip3, and it overwrote on the existing file and it's working now. I can install the packages as i need them in future. However, i can't access the old site-packages using pip3, how can i clean that up?

Comment: If you're not planning on using your Python 3.7 environment, just remove the Python 3.7 site-packages directory.